# React Native Expo app showing two topbars

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm following this example: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation#a-native-stack-navigator-for-each-tab

I've copy pasted the example from the website. However, this is what I see:
[image]

I've the following packages in package.json:

```
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
```

Here's my code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

import Ionicons from '@expo/vector-icons/Ionicons';

function DetailsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Details!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function SettingsScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Settings screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function AnalyticsScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Analytics screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const HomeStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function HomeStackScreen() {
  return (
    <HomeStack.Navigator>
      <HomeStack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
      <HomeStack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
    </HomeStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const SettingsStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function SettingsStackScreen() {
  return (
    <SettingsStack.Navigator>
      <SettingsStack.Screen name="SettingsScreen" component={SettingsScreen} />
      <SettingsStack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
    </SettingsStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const AnalyticsStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function AnalyticsStackScreen() {
  return (
    <AnalyticsStack.Navigator>
      <AnalyticsStack.Screen name="Analytics" component={SettingsScreen} />
      <AnalyticsStack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
    </AnalyticsStack.Navigator>
  )
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
            let iconName;

            if (route.name === 'Home') {
              iconName = 'home';
            } else if (route.name === 'Settings') {
              iconName = 'search';
            } else if (route.name === 'Analytics') {
              iconName = 'bar-chart'
            }

            // You can return any component that you like here!
            return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
          },
          tabBarActiveTintColor: 'tomato',
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'gray',
        })}
      >
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStackScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsStackScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Analytics" component={AnalyticsStackScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily hide navigator headers like this:

```
<YourNavigator.Navigator
  screenOptions={{ headerShown: false /* <-- This will hide your header */ }}
>
  <YourNavigator.Screen
    name='Settings' /* <-- This name will be shown as header if true */
    component={YourSettingsNavigator}
  />
</YourNavigator.Navigator>
```

Since `YourSettingsNavigator` is another Navigator, you are nesting navigators in each other. When doing this make sure to set `headerShown: false` in at least one of the navigators or you get two headers.